# Reconnecting MySQL on timeout

Tags: python, mysql, orm, mysql-python, peewee

I have a Python program which runs on background for weeks, and does database queries every once in a while. For that, I am using the ORM [`peewee`](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (version 2.2.1). I am using `MySQL` as a backend.

Lately I've encountered a recurring problem with accessing the DB, usually after days of running the program. The error which is raised by `peewee` is

```
peewee.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

The traceback is deep in `peewee`. I post it here, but as my `virtualenv` makes filenames too long, I am shortening them:

```
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2910, in save
    ret_pk = self.insert(**field_dict).execute()
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2068, in execute
    return self.database.last_insert_id(self._execute(), self.model_class)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1698, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2232, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2104, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_value.args), traceback)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2223, in execute_sql
    res = cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
peewee.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

**Possible solution attempts I've found:**

- In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117098/hard-to-debug-mysql-server-has-gone-away), one of the comments suggest pinging the `MySQL` server every once in a while to keep it (the connection?) alive. I am not sure how to do it via the ORM, though. (should I simply `SELECT 1` every hour, say?)
- In [this github peewee issue](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/239), which was opened 4 months ago, the same error is referred, though, it is claimed there that it is solved (and I am using a newer version).
- In a [7 year old issue](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/3645) of `trac`, one suggestion is to increase the timeout of `MySQL` for 3 days.
- In this [forum discussion](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/mysql-db-stops-responding-after-some-time), the option of increasing `MySQL`'s timeout is suggested, but an alternative of "using the autoReconnect option for the MySQL JDBC connector" is offered. I tried to figure out if such an option exists for Python's `MySQLdb` module, but couldn't find.
- I have found this [MySQL reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html) on reconnection behaviour, but it's a bit complicated for my understanding of `MySQL` (usually I work only with ORMs), and I don't know how to apply any of it from `peewee`.

Even if I'm able to ping the database to keep the connection alive for longer periods, I think it is considered a bad practice to keep a connection alive when one doesn't really need it. Is there any way to reopen the connection via the ORM? I consider both pinging and increasing the timeout of `MySQL` as workarounds, while a real solution would be to reconnect when needed (and a real solution is what I'm asking for).

Comment: Check the value of `wait_timeout` in MySQL

Comment: I guess it is 8 hours; isn't that the default?

Comment: Just manually call `db.close()` when you're done with the connection.

Comment: I'm never "done" with it; the program just keeps running. Still, I don't think it's a good practice to keep the connection alive if I'm not using it; and any timeout I'll set might not be large enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to catch the exception and based on which error, reconnect or to do something else. Whether it is a connection time out, or a network problem or the MySQL had to be restarted.

The below (pseudoish) code shows how you could do that, but there is more to it. You'll want to try a few times and then bail out, or maybe try every 2 minutes or so.

```
while True:
    try:
        # do your database stuff
    except peewee.OperationalError as exc:
        # Oops! We have to try to reconnect
```

Does not really matter whether you use an ORM or not. However, an ORM might offer this functionality.

Comment: That looks indeed like the proper thing to do. However, it was not easy to accomplish; there was no single method I could find that I could wrap with such a `try... except` structure, each time the error was raised from a different place. That's what nice - and problematic - about ORMs; they become almost transparent in your code. Anyway, I ended up pinging the server, and hopefully `peewee` people will implement an inner optional reconnect method one day.

Comment: In such extreme cases, you can put the try/except around the main() method of your script.

Comment: No, I'll never do that... It is not a script, it is a huge multi-threaded software... I just claim it's the responsibility of the ORM, otherwise I must "invade" its territory, making it redundant.

Comment: I've found that a generic "reconnect and try again" approach doesn't always work. specifically if the query you are re-trying is a prepared statement. If it is prepared, it would need to be "re-prepared" after the connection is established which can be trickier than you'd think depending on abstractions in place.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and for peewee using MySQLdb I got the following solution when initialize the MySQL database instance:

```
db = MySQLDatabase(db_name, user=db_username, passwd=db_password, host=db_host, port=db_port)
db.get_conn().ping(True)
```

where for the ping function there is:

> Checks whether or not the connection to the server is working. If it
>   has gone down, an automatic reconnection is attempted.
>
> This function can be used by clients that remain idle for a long
>   while, to check whether or not the server has closed the connection
>   and reconnect if necessary.
>
> New in 1.2.2: Accepts an optional reconnect parameter. If True, then
>   the client will attempt reconnection. Note that this setting is
>   persistent. By default, this is on in MySQL<5.0.3, and off thereafter.
>
> Non-standard. You should assume that ping() performs an implicit
>   rollback; use only when starting a new transaction. You have been
>   warned.

in the `db.get_conn().ping.__doc__`. Mind that `db.get_conn().ping(True)` has to be used if you create another connection again. So if you reconnect (through `db.connect()` for example) you must repeat the ping.

Comment: Pinging before running a query is considered an anti-pattern that wastes resources and is unreliable: https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/05/05/checking-for-a-live-database-connection-considered-harmful/

Comment: Every time you ping the database, a cute dolphin is killed.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.

My solution is use mysql connection pool `PooledMySQLDatabase` from `playhouse.pool` module.

please read: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/239

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.pool import *
```

Comment: Just a side note: this module is considered experimental, and it may be dangerous to apply it for production.