# Access variable of nested Class in python

Tags: python, mysql, nested-attributes, bottle, peewee

I'm using Peewee and bottle.py for a very small WebApp. Once in a while I get a `MySQLDatabase has gone away Error`, which my script doesn't seem to recover from.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852760/reconnecting-mysql-on-timeout), I should simply try-catch the error and recover myself.
An example of what I have:

```
def create_db_con():
    return peewee.MySQLDatabase("db_name", host="host", user="user", passwd="pass")

class ModelObj(peewee.Model):
    #some member ommited
    class Meta:
        database=create_db_con()

@route("/")
def index_htm():
    try:
        mo = ModelObj.filter(foo="bar")
    catch OperationalError, oe:
        ModelObj.Meta.database = create_db_con()
```

gives me the AttributeError in case of the OperationalError:

`AttributeError: type object 'OrderProdukt' has no attribute 'Meta'`

**How am I supposed to recover from this situation**?

**EDIT:**
As univerio pointed out, I can access it via `ModelObj._meta.database`, but it doesn't seem to work to just create it new. 
Is this a default python behavior for nested classes?

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py#L2861) it looks like the `Meta` class gets converted to a `ModelOptions` instance, available at `ModelObj._meta`.

Comment: Did you try with a instance of ModelObj? ModelObj().Meta.database